# Как создать скрипт формирования справки на js?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как реализовать, что почитать на эту тему, так у меня базовые знания js.

На сайте будет форма (на wordpress скорее всего) где пользователи вводят данные, а из этих данных будет формироваться бланк(справка) (наверно в формате html или pdf) .

Этот документ будет отправляться на почту админа сайта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для начала думаю? вам стоит ознакомиться с этим материалом . ["Интерфейс пользователя — Википедия"](http://%22%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F%22) . далее там же на википедии ["Веб-интерфейс"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81).
потом можно почитать на **mozilla.org** ["веб формы клиент-сервер"](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Client-Server_overview).  после можно ознакомиться с статейкай опять на википедосе [Веб-шаблон](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD). потом переходим к ознакомлению с **"MV-паттернам для проектирования веб-приложений"** здесь  поможет гугл или яндекс. 
вот как то так ))) потом приступайте к выполнению задач (реализации сбытмчт), и если будут появляться сложности то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) на ваших *примерах*, вам помогут найти оптимальное решение.